# changing directory in ipython notebook

Tags: git, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am creating a presentation on version control using ipython notebook so i need to create a and change to that directory .
After that need to `git init` that directory
so here's the issue ,

```
!cd "work"  # i have created a directory called work
!git init
```

so when the git init gets executed the repo is initialized in the root of the ipython notebook , not in the `work` directory .Its seems that each of these shell commands are executed in a instance of shell so 
How can i init a repo in the `work` directory?

Also after this command I will be working with the repo so a solution which changes the working directory temporarily  would do . eg-

```
!git commit
```

note - here `!` is used to execute shell command in ipython notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixing the command with bang `!` only effects that command. When the `!cd` command completes, you will be returned to the previous directory. Instead use the magic prefix `%cd` to change your working directory.

Comment: then use !git as before or is there a magic function for that as well?

Comment: Use `!git`. The magic prefix is limited to specific magic command. Try `%magic` for complete list of available commands.